# Eight-shaped orbit determination

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, coordinate-systems

I was playing a game on my smartphone whose goal is to draw certain orbit in presence of certain central gravitational potential. I noticed that when there are two center of force is possible to have a eight(or lemniscate)-shaped orbit. I would like to find analytical solution to that problem in the most symmetric situation:
I have a potential such as

$$
V=-\frac{1}{d_1}-\frac{1}{d_2}
$$

where

$d_1=\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$ and $d_2=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}$.

I would like to write down the equation of orbit in the having as initial conditions: $x(0)=0$, $y(0)=0$, $x'(0)=v\cos{θ}$, $y'(0)=v\sin{θ}$.

Of course in euclidean coordinates the square roots makes the problem difficult (Mathematica doesn't succede in solving them analytically). I was thinking what is the most clever system of coordinates but I'm a bit doubtful.

Do you know any book or paper that solves this problem that seems very simple?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31201/50583; Note that this is a three-body problem and thus it's not clear that you should expect an *analytical* solution to exist.

Comment: I read that post but it's not discussing about how to solve it.

Comment: The solution, if it exists, is unstable - that is, a small perturbation over time will change the orbit. But presumably you already discovered this when you played your game.

Comment: I noticed that the solution is unstable. My question was simply if anyone knows a way to write down the equation of the orbit, exactly with the above initial condition, disregarding stability issues

Comment: This is not a true 3-body problem because the two force centers are fixed.

Comment: @LewisMiller This is what I suspected, but I'm not an expert of the definitions.

Comment: This is the problem of two fixed centers, first studied by Euler. Papers continue to be published on this subject to this day.