# Can planets orbiting a binary star trace out an orbit in the form of an 8 (or $\infty$-sign)?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, stability, binary-stars, three-body-problem

In [this](http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/ast122/lectures/lec10.html) article there is a lot explained about planets orbiting a binary star. It is said that a planet orbits the binary star around the CM of both stars. I couldn't find anything about planetary orbits (neither in other articles) of planets tracing out an $\infty$-form around the two stars. This picture in this article is showing the path I mean (the red line):

[image]

In the article, though, the red line isn't representing the trajectory I mean (I used it only to clarify what I mean), but it represents the (as is shown) the Roche lobes, which are explained in the article.

I think my question is clear by now: do there exist orbits of planets in a binary star system which make the trajectory I described?

Comment: There are quite a few idealized orbital solution that have been found over the centuries. [Here is one represented in a OSP simulation.](https://www.compadre.org/osp/items/detail.cfm?ID=7182) But real situations always involve perturbations, so stability is of critical importance. (I believe the simulated solution *is* stable, but some other ideal solutions are not.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31201/2451

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Might a planet perform figure-8 orbits around two stars?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31201/)

Comment: I would guess that a planet in such an orbit would not last very long.

Comment: The mentioned question perfectly answered my question. Well, almost. I would say such an orbit is impossible.