# Possible moon orbits about a torus world (donut or ringworld)

Tags: orbital-motion

Thinking about the "*objects falling in a mineshaft through the earth*" scenario, this doesn't work in general terms as coriolis effects would require a figure 8 orbit , (else the objects would scrape the inside of the shaft) requiring a figure 8 mineshaft. However if we expand the size of the "*mineshaft*" to that of the hole through a torus, a figure 8 orbit would be achievable.

Obviously many figure eight orbits would exist of a moon around a non-rotating donut world (or one spinning about it's axis of revolution) , but what if the donut were spinning end on , (or tilted). There would be some subset of figure eight orbits that would be spin synchronous. i.e. the moon passes through the hole at say 0degrees, then a little while later, the donut has rotated 90degrees and the moon goes back through the hole again. It would seem there are many interesting orbital possibilities here, not sure whether you could call them "precessional" or "coriolis" or "schuler" or "harmonic" orbits .

So the question: **how would one calculate these orbits**,
and how to **determine if tentative orbits are stable** (i.e. some partial derivative would determine re-convergence as a consequence of minor pertubations (or tidal drag) .
.

I have drawn a "time lapse" view , looking along the spin axis , at 4 time intervals 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 .  Interestingly enough, a viewer on the "outer" surface of the planet would see the moon shoot across the sky from east to west, then from west to east each day , while a viewer on the inside would see 4 passes per day E-W , W-E, E-W, W-E. Other places on donut world would see the moon stop and retrace it's path.

[image: Donut world and moon orbit]

Comment: OK , after looking at the similar questions SE tagged after I posted this, it would seem that the first answer to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31201/ probably applies here, i.e. any figure-eight orbits would be marginally stable at best.

Comment: +1 for imagination. A figure 8 might only be marginally stable, but there are certainly some interesting stable orbits. Suppose the torus was like a hula hoop - a thin rod bent into a large circle. You can imagine a stable orbit close to the hoop. Now give additional velocity along the loop. Now you have a spiral orbit. Or imagine an orbit in the plane of the hoop and just outside it.

Comment: @mmesser314 there seem to be many possibilities, I guess it's the rotationally symettric equivalent of planets orbiting a binary star , There are three  types of orbit (a) at a large distance away orbiting the centre of mass, (b) a real close in orbit around one star and (c) a very thin region where a figure 8 orbit is possible.  Binary stars however need to orbit each other quite quickly , thus limiting the available figure 8 orbits, a ringworld on the other hand can be stationary or slowly rotating..